# how to implement a callback function in UFT vbscript

Tags: vbscript, callback

I've tried to search online but couldn't find the answer I need. Here's my task and requirement.  I have 2 function, the first one checks a condition and returns True and False.  The 2nd one starts a timer and checks the results of the 1st function periodically and only exit when the return value becomes True.  Here's my 2 funcitons

```
' the 1st one checks if an item exists in JavaList
Public Function existInJavaList(ByRef javaList, ByVal itemName)
    Dim itemcount, i, ret
    ret = False
    itemcount = javaList.GetROProperty("items count")
    For i=0 to itemcount -1
        If javaList.GetItem(i) = itemName Then
            ret = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    existInJavaList = ret
End Function

' the 2nd one checks the condition every 10 seconds and if the condition is True, 
' it returns True.  Otherwise, it times out after 120 seconds and returns False. 

Function waitForCondition(ByVal condition)
    Dim startTime, existFlag, accumulateTime

    startTime = Timer()
    existFlag = True

    Do Until CBool(condition)

        wait(10)

        TimeElapsed = Timer()
        If TimeElapsed - StartTime > 120 Then
            existFlag = False
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    waitForCondition = existFlag
End Function
```

How do I pass the 1st function as a parameter of the 2nd function so it's called every 10 seconds in the 2nd function?

Appreciate any advice.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, my original post was not formatted properly.  I've reposted here

```
Function existInJavaList(ByRef javaList, ByVal itemName)
    Dim itemcount, i, ret
    ret = False
    itemcount = javaList.GetROProperty("items count")
    For i=0 to itemcount -1
        If javaList.GetItem(i) = itemName Then
            ret = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    existInJavaList = ret
End Function

Function waitForCondition(ByVal condition)
    Dim startTime, existFlag, accumulateTime

    startTime = Timer()
    existFlag = True

    Do Until CBool(condition)

        wait(10)

        TimeElapsed = Timer()
        If TimeElapsed - StartTime > 120 Then
            existFlag = False
           Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

   waitForCondition = existFlag
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
itemExists = waitForCondition(GetRef("existInJavaList"), Array(javaList, itemName))

Public Function existInJavaList(arrArgs)
    Dim itemcount, i, ret, javaList, itemName
    Set javaList = arrArgs(0)
    itemName = arrArgs(1)
    ret = False
    itemcount = javaList.GetROProperty("items count")
    For i = 0 to itemcount -1
        If javaList.GetItem(i) = itemName Then
            ret = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    existInJavaList = ret
End Function

Function waitForCondition(condition, arrArgs)
    Dim startTime, TimeElapsed, existFlag, accumulateTime
    startTime = Timer()
    existFlag = True
    Do Until condition(arrArgs)
        wait(10)
        TimeElapsed = Timer()
        If TimeElapsed - StartTime > 120 Then
            existFlag = False
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    waitForCondition = existFlag
End Function
```